# Plot vectors with labels in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I have a Nx62 matrix with N 62-D vectors and a NX1 vector with the labels for the vectors. I am trying to plot these vectors with their labels because I want to see the behavior of these classes when plotted in a 62-dimensional space. The vectors belong to three classes according to the labels of a NX1 vector cited before.

How to to that in matlab? when i do plot(vector,classes) the result is very weird to analyse, how to put labels in the graph?

The code i am using to get the labels, vectors and plotting is the following:

```
%labels is a vector with labels, vectors is a matrix where each line is a vector
[labels,vectors]=libsvmread('features-im1.txt');
```

when I plot a three dimensional vector is simple

```
a=[1,2,3]
plot(a)
```

and then I get the result

[image: Simple plot]

but now i have a set of vectors and a set of labels, and i want to see the distribution of them, i want to plot each of these labels but also want to identify their classes. How to do that in matlab?

EDIT: This code is almost working. The problem is the fact that for each vector and class the plot will assign a color. I just want three colors and three labels, one per class.

```
[class,vector]=libsvmread('features-im1.txt'); 
%the plot doesn't allow negative and 0 values in the label 
class=class+2; 
labels = {'class -1','class 0','class 1'}; 
h = plot(vector); 
legend(h,labels{class})
```

Comment: Show us your code for plotting. How have you managed to visualize a 62 dimensional space?

Comment: @Dan: I would like to see a 62 dimensional space too!

Comment: I'm sorry. I know it is hard to see a 62 dimensional space :-). I have a set of vectors belonging to class 1, -1 and 0. I am suspecting that the vectors from the classes are very similar and I want to confirm that. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this does what you want:

```
N = 5;
classes = [1 2 3 1 2]; % class of each vector. Size N x 1
colors = {'r', 'g', 'b'}; % you can also define them numerically
matrix = rand(N,62); % example data. Size N x 62
labels = {'class 1','class 2','class 3'}; % class names. Size max(classes) x 1
h = plot(matrix.');
h_first = NaN(1,3); % initialization
for k = 1:max(classes)
    ind = find(classes==k);
    set(h(ind), 'color', colors{k}) % setting color to all plots of a given class
    h_first(k) = h(ind(1)); % remember a handle of each color (for legend)
end
legend(h_first,labels)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is this part of the code a comment? 'class names. Size max(classes) x 1'

Comment: @mad Yes, sorry. Corrected

Comment: The problem with your code is the fact that for each pair vector,class the plot will use a different color and a different legend in the plot. For example, 3 vectors from class 0 will have three different colors and three entries in the legend, instead of just one color and just one entry in the legend.

Suppose I want three entries in the legend (class -1, 1 and 0) and three different colors, one for each class, and assign these colors for the vectors according to the class of them. How to do that?

Comment: @mad Try it now and tell me